# Sybase Distributed Transaction not working in .Net

Tags: .net, transactions, sybase, distributed

I am using Sybase ASE 16 and trying to create distrusted transaction in .Net. Following is my code that works fine with SQL Server but not with Sybase ASE database:

```
public void DistTransaction()
    {
        try
        {
            var op = new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
            };

            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,op))
            {
                Transaction tx1 = Transaction.Current;

                var tx = (System.EnterpriseServices.ITransaction)(TransactionInterop.GetDtcTransaction(Transaction.Current));

                using (AseConnection conn1 = new AseConnection(connstring))
                {

                    using (AseConnection conn2 = new AseConnection(connstring))
                    {

                        conn1.Open();
                        conn2.Open();
                        conn1.EnlistDistributedTransaction(tx);
                        conn2.EnlistDistributedTransaction(tx);
                        //conn1.EnlistTransaction(tx1);
                        //conn2.EnlistTransaction(tx1);

                        using (AseCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd1.CommandText = "insert into dbo.Table1(Name) values('bnm')";

                            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }

                        using (AseCommand cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            cmd2.CommandText = "insert into dbo.Table2(Id) values(45)";

                            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                }

                scope.Complete();

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

The second query gets fail and it should rollback the first query but it doesn't do in Sybase ASE. I also enabled the DTM in Sybase but no difference.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Too complex to diagnose quickly... but I would recommend stepping through the program and watching the system tables like systransactions to see if the open transactions are appearing as you expect them.